# XGBoost Algorithm: Impact of Scaling Instance Weights

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, gradient-descent

Does scaling the instance weights impact the XGBoost ML Model training?

The instance weights determine the importance of each data point during the training process. The XGBoost ML Model uses instance weights to multiply gradients in the learning process.

I am reviewing the literature and can not find any relevant paper.

Comment: I think this question is duplicate to: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457483/sample-weights-in-xgbclassifier

Comment: XGBoost has both a linear model and a tree model. The tree model is not sensitive to scaling (nor to any invertible affine transformation in general). See this answer for more details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353462/what-are-the-implications-of-scaling-the-features-to-xgboost